# Proper Case in Athena SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, case, amazon-athena, presto

I'm new to Athena and trying to convert a field 'Country' to Proper Case. For example:

> united states -> United States

Is there a way to do this in Athena?

Comment: Can you do the conversion to initial caps in the presentation layer? That's where it's meant to be done. Also, it might make sense to use ISO 3166-1 alpha-3 for the country and translate that in the presentation layer in case a country changes its name.

Comment: Yes. I was able to do something similar to this: select * from 

(SELECT split(country,' ') as result FROM "leads_db"."test_leads")

where
lower(element_at(result,1)) = element_at(result,1) or lower(element_at(result,2)) = element_at(result,2); But this doesn't seem efficient

Comment: It's just an idea.. My thought is to capitalize the first letter in each word from the list I get and concatenate the result. But I think there should be an easy way

Comment: [Athena engine version 2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/presto-functions.html)'s [RegEx section](https://prestodb.io/docs/0.217/functions/regexp.html) gives as example for

`regexp_replace(string, pattern, function)`

`SELECT regexp_replace('new york', '(\w)(\w*)', x -> upper(x[1]) || lower(x[2])); --'New York'`
Would that work for you?

Comment: @Abecee Can you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turning a comment into an answer:

[Athena engine version 2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/presto-functions.html) gives in its [RegEx section](https://prestodb.io/docs/0.217/functions/regexp.html) as example for
`regexp_replace(string, pattern, function)`

```
SELECT regexp_replace('new york', '(\w)(\w*)', x -> upper(x[1]) || lower(x[2])); --'New York'
```